# $routeProvider stopped working from absolute path

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

Weird thing happened. It was working fine. I have not changed anything related to routes, but it stopped working when accessed using an absolute path.

Here's what I have in app.js:

```js
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/entry.html'
      })
      .when('/orderstatus/:routeParam', {
        controller: 'controllerController',
        templateUrl: '/app/views/page.html'
      })
      
      ...etc.etc
```

If I access "orderstatus" with parameter from inside the website, e.g. I navigate to the website.com, then access this route, it works fine.

But if I access it using an absolute path, e.g.

https://website.com/index.html#/orderstatus/24c98f38-190d-4a0c-86a2-49fb5f4d68fb

it redirects back to https://website.com/index.html#/

It used to work fine. I need this direct path because we email the customer order confirmation, and they can click on the link and get to the order confirmation page directly.

Now it does not work all of a sudden. I am totally perplexed as to why this could have happened. Like I said, it worked before.

If that matters, I am referencing a CDN at
https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/angular-route.min.js

and regular angular js at:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Live and learn.

One of my directives that's included in index.html was redirecting to the root on error.

ng-route was working fine and as expected.